# remote desktop from windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vnc, rdp

I try to connect from windows 7 pro, to an ubuntu machine (14.4 LTS).
I've installed `xrdp` and managed to connect to it (using username and password) from the windows rdp-client, the problem was that it gave me a blank-gray-pattern screen, with an X cursor.

I've also installed `XVNCserver11`, and tried to connect to it using echovnc client; the error was: no security type suitable for RFB 3.3 supported.

I've tried running the `sudo vncserver`, which started something in the background, but gave the same error as `xvncserver11`

Not sure what to to next
any help will be appreciated

### edit

this is the file

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
  . /etc/default/locale
  export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

startfxce4

. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

### edit 2

this is the xrdp problem (occurred again after all steps in the below answer)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xrdp` but still you have to determine which session to use when remoting.

first Install xrdp:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Install XFCE4 or any other supported:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Edit our `.xsession` file in your home:

```
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
```

Edit  `startwm.sh` file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

In the `wm_start()` Add the line `startxfce4` just directly under:

```
 if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    export LANG LANGUAGE
  fi
```

so the function looks like:

```
wm_start()
{
  if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    export LANG LANGUAGE
  fi

startxfce4


  # debian
  if [ -r /etc/X11/Xsession ]; then
    . /etc/X11/Xsession
    exit 0
  fi
.....

}
```

Now save and exit then restart xrdp.

```
sudo service xrdp restart
```

Now you can connect normally to your Ubuntu using xfce for remote sessions.